# While running the app in debug view, is there anyway you can click on a component in code and have it highlighted in the app (or vice versa)?

Tags: flutter

While running the app in debug view, is there anyway you can click on a component in code and have it highlighted in the app (or vice versa)?

Edit: For instance on a website you can view the inspector and highlight the element that is currently under the cursor, etc. Trying to find the same thing for flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Flutter Inspector 
For detail please reference  https://medium.com/pslove/flutter-widget-inspector-aa7c828854d6 
There is a video inside document

official document Using the Flutter inspector https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector

[image]